# How to send emails with attachment in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I would like to send a csv file through email. I found a plugin - flutter_mailer. But it doesn't support iOS.
Then I tried using platform codes, but android shows **android.os.FileUriExposedException**. I tried resolving using adding < provider > fields to manifest file, but that is also not working.
Which is the best way to resolve this email issue?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not at all the best thing to do, but right now, I feel this is the most reliable way to handle such things so don't freak out too early.

Write a firebase function to send an email and use firebase database to trigger it or directly make a rest call.